# How to destroy Activex control reference refresh the page simultaneously

Tags: c#, activex

Use C # to create Activex controls file monitoring, the purpose of the existence of the new file upload. Refresh the page when a problem arises, Activex control reference was not able to destroy. Originally created objects still exist, the new object has been created. Two object references are at work, the original object has been unable to interact with the page. How to destroy the object references refresh the page at the same time? You can understand my question?

translate:https://translate.google.co.jp